# Handling exceptions raised in get_context_data of class based view

Tags: python, django, exception

I have an app with class based views. Each view inherits from the base view defined earlier.

Said view (and all of its descendants) implements `get_context_data` method which can throw exceptions under some conditions.

I would like to catch these exceptions and render specific template.

Basically views.py looks like this

```
class BaseView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(**ctx):
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**ctx)
        if condition:
            raise CustomException('Condition was met')
        # code that adds values into context dictionary
        # like context['somevar'] = somevalue
        ...

        return context

class SpecificView1(BaseView):
    def get_context_data(**ctx):
        context = super(SpecificView1, self).get_context_data(**ctx)
        # code that updates values in context dictionary
        ...
        return context
```

I've tried to insert a new class into views hierarchy (renaming `BaseView` into `OriginalBaseView`)

```
class BaseView(OriginalBaseView):
    def get_context_data(**ctx):
    context = {}
    try:
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**ctx)
    except RepoException:
       self.template_name = 'specific_template.html'
    return context
```

But using this approach would mean that I will have to update all descendant `get_context_data` methods with checks that keys they update are in `context`.

Is there a way to better handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own middleware which will handle `RepoException` and render `specific_template.html`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#exception-middleware

This way you can throw `RepoException` anywhere in view and your template will be rendered automatically.

Answer (score 3):

batiskaf answer seems to be right. You basically need to put a middleware in place which processes your view exceptions. This middleware can either send None in which case the exception gets handled, or a HTTP Response , which can have your template.html rendered.

```
    def process_exception(exception, *args, **kwargs):
        error_code = getattr(exception, 'code', 500) #you can use codes if you want
        if not isinstance(exception, MyBaseException):
        request = kwargs.get('request') #you can use request to load the template
     return {
          'status': 0,
          'message': exception.message,
          'error_code': error_code
     } #or send an HttpResponse with your template.
```

Hope this helps :)